# Repeatable off-by-one issue in Common Lisp's format

Tags: common-lisp

I have `format`'s tabs `~VT` behaving differently depending on whether the newline `~%` is at the beginning or the end of lines, and I wanted to know why.  The difference is that when the newline is at the end of lines, there seems to be an extra space in the *first instance only*  of the tab  stop.  The following examples illustrate.  The only difference in the examples is in the format-control string: it's `"~%~A~VT= ~A"` in the first example and `"~A~VT= ~A~%"` in the second.

#### EXAMPLE 1: newline at the beginning of output lines

```
(let ((sb (make-array 0
                :element-type 'character
                :adjustable t
                :fill-pointer 0)))
           (mapcar (lambda (line)
                     (format sb "~%~A~VT= ~A" line 10 42))
                   '(a abcd asdf foobar g november))
           sb)
"
A        = 42
ABCD     = 42
ASDF     = 42
FOOBAR   = 42
G        = 42
NOVEMBER = 42"
```

The behavior here is as expected.

#### EXAMPLE 2: newline at the ends of output lines

The thing to notice in this example is that the first line,

```
A         = 42
```

has one  more space in it than the corresponding line from example 1:

```
A        = 42
```

It's a little hard to see because of the leading double-quote, and that's why I snipped this out: to help you see them better.
This is repeatable on much bigger examples and is an MVE stripped out of a much larger program.

```
(let ((sb (make-array 0
                :element-type 'character
                :adjustable t
                :fill-pointer 0)))
           (mapcar (lambda (line)
                     (format sb "~A~VT= ~A~%" line 10 42))
                   '(a abcd asdf foobar g november))
           sb)
"A         = 42
ABCD     = 42
ASDF     = 42
FOOBAR   = 42
G        = 42
NOVEMBER = 42
"
```

The big-picture question is "why?"  I'm using SBCL 1.3.1 on a Mac and haven't tried it on other implementations.  It could be a bug, but it seems more plausible that it's intended behavior, but I don't understand what it could be intended to accomplish and I haven't been able to find an explanation in format's documentation.

Comment: Works for me in CCL and CLISP. (By the way, `mapc` is preferred for side effects.)

Comment: Same issue for CMUCL (snapshot-2016-01). Since SBCL is derived from it, maybe the problem has origin in that implementation.

Comment: @danlei -- I verified that CLISP does _not_ show the anomaly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it is a bug.  I can also reproduce it on Linux with SBCL 1.3.1.

`~T` may need heuristics (that can fail) to determine the current column in some cases, but I guess the start of the string should be considered column 0.

At least on my computer, it seems not to occur when a simple `with-output-to-string` is used:

```
(with-output-to-string (s)
  (mapcar (lambda (line)
            (format s "~A~VT= ~A~%" line 10 42))
          '(a abcd asdf foobar g november)))
```

It does occur, however, when you give the pre-made string to `with-output-to-string`:

```
(let ((sb (make-array 0
                      :element-type 'character
                      :adjustable t
                      :fill-pointer 0)))
  (with-output-to-string (s sb)
    (mapcar (lambda (line)
              (format s "~A~VT= ~A~%" line 10 42))
            '(a abcd asdf foobar g november))
    sb))
```

Comment: Note that the docs have some specific comments about determining the initial column, http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cfa.htm.

Comment: "If for some reason the current absolute column position cannot be determined by direct inquiry, format may be able to deduce the current column position by noting that certain directives (such as ~%, or ~&, or ~A with the argument being a string containing a newline) cause the column position to be reset to zero, and counting the number of characters emitted since that point."

Comment: "If that fails, format may attempt a similar deduction on the riskier assumption that the destination was at column zero when format was invoked. If even this heuristic fails or is implementationally inconvenient, at worst the ~T operation will simply output two spaces."