# output n spaces in Common Lisp

Tags: format, common-lisp

How can I output a **variable** number of spaces N using Lisp's format? It should be the equivalent of the C solution printf("%*c", N, ' ');

I know there is ~NT but what is the equivalent of the star? ~* seems to have another meaning in Lisp's format strings.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate;  this sounds similar to a question from a while back...

Comment: Yes, how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072959/lisp-format-a-character-a-number-of-times?

Comment: Yep, it is related in that it told me that the equivalent of * is ~v. Thanks. So the solution is: (format "~vT" N)

Comment: There is a problem with my solution: if N is 0 a space is printed just as if N were 1, but I want no space in this case. Is there a work-around to this problem? It's a weird behaviour IMHO, please explain me why it does work like this.

Comment: Are you using sbcl by any chance? There was a recent question about an extra space with ~t, [Repeatable off-by-one issue in Common Lisp's format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866049/repeatable-off-by-one-issue-in-common-lisps-format). You may want to use one of the other solutions on the other question, if that's the case.

Comment: No, I was using Lispworks. Yep, the other solutions work.